# Comments not visible after enabling the Google+ comments widget

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I was using the blogspot default commenting widget and only sometime back I linked my Google plus profile and enabled G+ comments to show on my blog. Ideally it had to show both the default blogger comments and G+comments but unfortunately I cannot see any.

I've approved the comments and the count shows on the blog but comments don't appear. I've uploaded a theme and hardly made any changes in the layout.

Any idea how to get both my comment widgets working?

Thanks.
Sowmya.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom Templates?

If you are then, you should know that custom templates doesn't have proper `Data Tags` added (most of the time) in their templates.

I've just made a test blog with default template and enabled the Google+ Comments feature, its successfully incorporated without any errors. So you need to work on your Uploaded template. (Take notes from the "Default Templates" Provided by the Blogger)

Comment: I have a semi-custom template. Cannot afford to change it now. Anyway I have resolved this issue. Thank you.